# How to move a file from MyDrive to Team Drive?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to use Google Apps Script to transfer a file from MyDrive to Team Drive.  I can do this manually (so I know I have permission) and I enabled the Drive API (so was able to save to MyDrive).  However, when I do this (which I got from another post):

```
function moveFileToFolder(fileId, newFolderId) {  
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileId, {supportsTeamDrives: true});

  Drive.Files.patch(file, fileId, {
    supportsTeamDrives: true,
    corpora:            'teamDrive',
    removeParents:      file.parents.map(function(f) { return f.id; }),
    addParents:         [newFolderId],    
  });
}
```

I get this error:

```
Sharing restrictions cannot be set on a Team Drive item.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It appears I was overthinking it as the following works:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TEAM_DRIVE_ID);
parentFolder.addFile(file);
```