# Move file from Drive to TeamDrive folder appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker, google-drive-shared-drive

I would like to transfer a file from MyDrive to TeamDrive with script from AppmMaker. I use DriveApp to create the file in MyDrive and with a DrivePicker widget from appmaker i get id from target folder to save the file.
DriveApp can move file in TeamDrive with

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(TEAM_DRIVE_ID);
parentFolder.addFile(file);
```

but not in a folders in TeamDrive.

I have try to use this code :

```
function moveFileToFolder(fileIds, newFolderId) {  
  var file = Drive.Files.get(fileIds, {supportTeamDrives: true,supportsTeamDrives: true});

  Drive.Files.patch(file, fileIds, {
    removeParents: file.parents.map(function(f) { return f.id; }),
    addParents: [newFolderId],
    supportTeamDrives: true,
    supportsTeamDrives: true
  });
}
```

I have the error "Sharing restrictions cannot be set on a Team Drive item."

Reference :[How to move a file from MyDrive to Team Drive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302468/how-to-move-a-file-from-mydrive-to-team-drive)

(the solution of the reference not work because i want to move it in a folder in teamdrive not directly in teamdrive)

Any Idea ?

Comment: Try using `update` instead of `patch`, or if you need to continue with `patch`, explicitly remove the various non-applicable metadata properties that exist on Drive files but not on Team Drive files.

Comment: Thanks for answer. `update` return the same error and I do not find any documentation about how to remove these various metadata.

Comment: You can explicitly control file metadata, so get the existing metadata, delete the inapplicable properties from this returned object, then supply it as the new metadata for the moved file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter to change in the file metadata because Drive file and Team Drive file are not the same. You can change it with

```
var file = Drive.Files.get(FileId);
file.capabilities.canMoveTeamDriveItem = true;
```

And after simply move it with

```
var fileDriveApp = DriveApp.getFileById(FileId); 
fileDriveApp.getParents().next().removeFile(fileDriveApp);
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(foldersId);
folder.addFile(fileDriveApp);
```

Reference : https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files

Comment: Your question is related with Moving file and provided answer is for creating new file. Please edit your question/answer appropriately so others don't get confused.